# How to change button programmatically without outlet connection in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a list of buttons inside an array. I want to replace the buttons position order using that array. I can do this in java, but cant do the same in swift. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var menuView: UIView!

struct ButtonsIndex {
  var button: UIButton
  var index: Int
}

var footer: [ButtonsIndex] = []

//Set Buttons order etc
...

func setFooter(){
 let count = 0
 for buttons in menuView.subviews {
  if var button = buttons as? UIButton {
   button = footer[count].button
   count += 1
  }
 }
}
```

Is it impossible to change the buttons position without connecting the outlets to my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You assign an array element to `button` but then don't do anything with `button` - What do you want to do to it?  In Java this code would have no effect either.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That is true. I have to pass that "button" to menuView!! Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Ricardinho you can change the position of buttons using two ways. The first way, you can update button frame in for loop and Second way is to use NSLayoutConstraint constant,

Comment: @Nilesh R Patel thanks for the information. I changed the menuView from stackView to collectionView. So I could change the position without any problems!